# How to open an empty gantt chart?

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, dhtmlx

In my web java application I need to create many projects so I need to open a new empty gantt everytime I want, the problem is that the table tasks contains other projects and if I want to create a new project the page will display all the old tasks, what can I do with this trick, please help. 
index.html

```
  <form action="newgantt.html">
 <input type="submit" value="gantt" >
</form>
```

newgantt.html

```
<body>
<div id="gantt_here" style="width:100%; height:500px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
           gantt.config.xml_date = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i";
            gantt.config.scale_unit = "day";
            gantt.config.duration_unit = "day";
            gantt.config.date_scale = "%d"; 
    gantt.init("gantt_here");
    gantt.load("Conector");
     var dp = new  dataProcessor("Conector");
    dp.init(gantt);
```

Conector.java

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONGanttConnector gantt = new JSONGanttConnector(conn, DBType.MySQL);
    gantt.servlet(req, res);
    gantt.mix("open", "1");
 gantt.enable_order("sortorder");
 gantt.render_links("gantt_links", "id", "source,target,type");
 gantt.render_table("tasks", "id","text", "start_date,duration,progress,sortorder");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only one object "gantt", is the reference of your gantt. If u want to create a new gantt, u need to destroy the old gantt and reload data :

```
if(gantt)
{
   gantt.destructor();
}
```

Or add new gantt object like this :

```
function init() {
    gantt1 = Gantt.getGanttInstance();
    gantt1.init("first");
    gantt1.parse(firstTask);

    gantt2 = Gantt.getGanttInstance();
    gantt2.init("second");
    gantt2.parse(secondTask);   
}


<body onload="init();">
    <div id="first" class="dhx_cal_container" ...>
        ...
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="gantt_here_2" class="dhx_cal_container" ...>
        ...
    </div>  
</body>
```